# Can I login to a protected directory via a link?

Tags: php, php4

I want to create links to pages and content that are in protected directories. I didn't program the protected directories I set them up from the host admin page.

I want to be able to give links to user that will take them to page and login as well.

Also if there is a way I want to be able to embed content from the protected directories in other places and not have the password box shop up in order to display the content.

I am using PHP4

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the authentication, you can use a URL like this:

```
http://username:password@yoursite.com/protected_dir
```

I know that works for simple protection via `.htaccess`. However, keep in mind that you will be sending that link with the password in clear text, and may be inadvertently seen by the wrong people.

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work, I just tried it again and it DID work for FF and Chrome but did not work for IE...strange.

Comment: I believe IE disabled this for security reasons in Windows XP SP2 and newer.

Comment: Regarding IE: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489 "Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses (HTTP or HTTPS URLs)"

Answer (score 0):

> Also if there is a way I want to be
>   able to embed content from the
>   protected directories in other places
>   and not have the password box shop up
>   in order to display the content.

Read it with fsockopen. Here's an example od fsockopen with basic authentication
http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#32830

Answer (score 0):

> ...I want to be able to embed content
>   from the protected directories in
>   other places and not have the password
>   box shop up in order to display the
>   content.

As a direct link this

```
http://username:password@yoursite.com/protected_dir/file.html
```

does not work, but only when attempting to see it with IE browser
I think if you want to embed contents via PHP you might use this:

```
file_get_contents("http://username:password@yoursite.com/protected_dir/file.html")
```

If you try this one, plz let me know, i'm interested too.